# Unable to get value from database on wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Hey guys so I am trying to grab a value from my database but for some reason its not turning out the way it should be.  I am calling everything through wordpress $wpdb.

CODE:

```
/***GET USERNAME***/
            global $current_user, $wpdb;
            get_currentuserinfo();
            $accusername = $current_user->user_login ;
            /******SEE IF FIRST TIME DISCOUNT CODE BEEN USED*******/
            $checkFTDiscount = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 
                "
                    SELECT firsttime_discount 
                    FROM $wpdb->users 
                    WHERE user-login = %d
                ", 
                $accusername
            ) );
            echo $checkFTDiscount;
```

So technically I should get the value 1 from this because in the data field its drawing from - which is an int(2) - is set to 1 for this user.

Let me know if you need any other info.

Thanks for the help!

EDITED

Once value is gotten it sets these -

```
if ($checkFTDiscount == 1){
                $validFTDiscount = 1;

            }
            else if ($checkFTDiscount == 0){
                $validFTDiscount = 0;

            }
```

This does not happen though.

Comment: So what is it doing that you are not wanting ti to do? Are you getting some errors?

Comment: It's not setting the values that I want and not echoing anything.

Comment: Are you getting errors?  Do you have `error_reporting` and `display_errors` on?  Have you done any var_dumps or made any debugging attempts at all?

Comment: Only just trying to echo stuff but nothing happens with that value.

Comment: `echo`ing and doing actual `var_dump`s or `print_r`s is not the same thing.  Are you looking at error logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example

```
WHERE user-login = %d // %d for integers
```

should be

```
WHERE user_login = %s // %s for string and it's a string value and _ instead of -
```

Comment: Did not realize it was something that simple...we like to over complicate things :)  Thanks for telling me the %d and %s I did not know that!